# Problem related to Riemann mapping theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\omega$ be a proper simple connected sub domain of $\mathbb C$. Let $z_1$and $z_2$ be two distinct points of $\omega$ and let $f$ and $g$ be two analytic automorphisms of $\omega$ i.e conformal bijection $\omega \to \omega$ such that $f(z_1)=g(z_1), f(z_2)=g(z_2)$. Prove that $f=g$

My idea is first to prove this for the unit disk and then use the existence of Riemann mapping theorem. Can you help me in proving this for unit disk?

Comment: It is *Riemann*.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Without loss, take $z_1 = 0$. Then we have

$$g^{-1}f(0) = 0$$

and $$g^{-1}f(z_2) = z_2$$

Now $g^{-1}f$ is an analytic map from $\mathbb{D}$ to itself that fixes $0$, so what does the Schwarz lemma imply?

Comment: ok We can use automorphism of unit disk to map $z_1$ to $0$ but how can we say that $z_2$ will still be a fixed point? I am stuck here

Comment: @Mathematician Sorry, I meant $g^{-1} f$ in those places. Then we have $g^{-1} f(0) = g^{-1} g(0) = 0$, and likewise for $z_2$: $$g^{-1}f(z_2) = g^{-1} g(z_2) = z_2$$

Answer (score 0):

Use a conformal map to map $z_1,z_2,f,g$ in $\Bbb D$ and use Schwarz's Lemma to show that only the identity map has two fixed points. Use  the Moebius tranformation $ φ_a$ and let h$=φ_{a}o\overline g^{-1} o \overline f o φ_{-a}$ with $\overline g,\overline f$ being the image of $f,g$ by the conformal map into $\Bbb D$